# how to build and use the local wallet with raw transaction?

Tags: web3js, transactions

I want to implement my own wallet on the client side instead of using metamask extension. if I understand it correctly, the method of using my own wallet is to use the private key of the generated account to sign any transactions client-side, and then relay them to a public node for execution.

The code below is the to sign the transaction offline.

```
  sendSigned(txData,wallet_privatekey, cb) {
      var web3 = this.web3;
      const tx = new Tx(txData);
      var _pk = wallet_privatekey.slice(2);
      var privateKey = new Buffer(_pk, 'hex');
      tx.sign(privateKey);
      const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), cb);
  }

  sendData(fromAddress,toAddress,wallet_privatekey) {
    var web3 = this.web3;
    var self = this;
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress).then(txCount => {
        console.log("nonce:" + txCount);
        const txData = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.00000009', 'ether')),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(30000),
            to: toAddress,
            value: web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.0001', 'ether')),
            data: web3.utils.asciiToHex('hello'),
            //chainId: 1
        }
        self.sendSigned(txData,wallet_privatekey, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return
            console.log('error', err)
            console.log('sent', result)
        })
    })
  }
```

however I still don't know how to sign each action on the contract, for example, I have a exampler contract below

```
contract LocalExample {
address public owner;
    function setOwner(address _newOwner)  external {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
}
```

on the client, the code for execution the setOwner method is as below

```
 contract.methods.setOwner(owner_address)
                            .send({from: account,value:value,gas:210000,gasPrice:5000000000 })
                            .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                               console.log('hash',hash);
                            })
                            .on('receipt', function(receipt){
                               console.log('receipt',receipt);
                            })
```

using the client code for execution will only trigger the metamask, so my final question is how to combine the client code with creating a raw transaction in order to use the local wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web3js to generate the data-value. Then you can sign the transaction manually with your private-key and send it to the blockchain via web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.

```
const EthCrypto = require('eth-crypto');
const txDataField = contractInstance.setOwner(YourOwnerAddress).encodeABI();

// create+sign the transaction
const rawTx = {
    from: signerAddress,
    to: contractAddress,
    nonce: 0,
    gasLimit: 5000000,
    gasPrice: 5000000000,
    data: txDataField
};
const serializedRecieveTx = EthCrypto.signTransaction(
    rawTx,
    signerPrivateKey
);

// submit the tx
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedRecieveTx);
```

Actually I made [a tutorial](https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto/blob/master/tutorials/signed-data.md#recover-the-signature-on-the-blockchain) on how to send data-txs to the chain

Answer (score 1):

The data value in your transaction object is wrong. If you want to execute a contract's function you should use something like this:

```
var address = '0x...';
var data = web3.sha3("setOwner(address)").substr(0,10); //Function
data += web3.sha3(address).substr(0,32); //Attribute (if value starts with '0x' then use 'substr(2,32)'
```

Read [Interacting with smart contracts](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.html#interacting-with-smart-contracts) for more info.

To sign a transaction (offline) you'd use [Accounts signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction):

```
var tx = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txData, privateKey);
```

To send the tx (online) use [sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction):

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx.rawTransaction);
```